# How do I get the owner or parent of a react component

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way for a react child component to find out its parent without explicitly adding a ref on the parent, that is passed to the child?

Perhaps some undocumented property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a _owner property, but it's intended to be private, so it is not guaranteed that it will remain accessible in future react releases.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this._owner.props); // Logs parent props-object.
}
```

However, as this will probably stop working one day and I want my conscience to be clean, it forces me to suggest that you pass a callback or refactor how the data flows in your application.

Comment: Thanks a perfect answer.   Normally I would agree with your comment, but the reason I am doing this is to ease the reusability of a component.  I will put in an issue on github and perhaps _owner can be made standard.

Comment: Sometimes I use a delegate pattern to solve this, so the parent calls the child as `<Child delegate={this}/>`